# jquery asp.net application structure

Tags: jquery, asp.net, url, directory, structure

I am planning a large web application and want to organise the application into folders:
    /Products
    /Orders
    /Staff
    /Utils

The application could well end up with a hundred or more pages and I don't want all of them in the root folder.

However, I see in the jQuery UI library that a lot of the css will reference an images folder.

Is there a best way to structure this application so that if a page is loaded from a sub-folder or even sub-sub folder that the javascript css links will still work? Or must I dive in and rewrite the jQuery UI library with PHP or ASP.NET so it produces the correct references to images?

I know I could probably do a search and replace for 
url(images/xyx.png) with 
url(/images/xyx.png) 
but I found that when I run my application from my web site that does not work.

This is because the web site is www.myhomepage/sales/xzy.apsx whereas at development time the URL is localhost:1234/xyz.aspx  so I had a problem with absolute url references. I can solve that by using runat=server tags, but again I don't fancy doing that all through the jquery-ui library if I can help it.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: image references in css files are relative to the css file, and not the pages that use the css.  Am I understanding your question properly?

Comment: if the problem is only the css images you can take a look at a base64 image embedding. 

http://johndyer.name/optimizing-css-with-base64-embedded-images-with-bonus-utility/.

Comment: @FiveTools : I though the css would be relative to the page that loaded the css file. I guess there are lots of facts I don't know clearly yet. Thanks for the answer.